# Can't upload anything to my server through SFTP using PhpStorm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp, phpstorm, sftp

I'm running a ec2 instance and transferring my PHP scripts through SFTP to my server. All has been working well up till today, suddenly I cannot transfer items to the server. Downloading the scripts back from the server works fine but I can't upload anything.

I have tried, resetting the ec2 instance and "Invalidate caches/reset" feature on PhpStorm, but I cannot get it to work. Frozen on this screen.

Really appreciate any help thanks!

[image]

Comment: Maybe do you have more details? like the log trace? Invalidate caches/reset may represent a lot of things

Comment: It just says "Upload file <file> to <location> , and does nothing

Comment: Why are you trying to this? Just saying FTP and SFTP are not the most save protocols to transfer data. Actually the industry is trying to kill them. I would suggest to use something like S3, upload your scripts in a private bucket and from your machine you can download it.

Comment: Appreciate your advice! I will look into that. To workaround this at the moment i just wrote the php files on the server using nano

Comment: Well if that's the reason you can always use ssh to share the files, isn't?

Comment: Invalidating caches have nothing to do with deployment/file transfer operations so should not affect it in any way. You may enable extra logging and check the log file for possible hints: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs P.S. Have you tried restarting you computer -- it may actually help when it's "suddenly stopped working". But then .. the download still works...